# How to republish GetStream messages to a new topic using IoT Core rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot-core

I'm trying to extract mqtt messages from the `$aws/things/+/streams/+/data/json` topic and republish it to a new topic such as `devices/data`. The SQL statement I have in the rule is: `SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/+/streams/+/data/json'`. I'm able to receive messages on the topic I want to republish, but for some reason those messages are not being republished to a new topic I defined in the rule.

The rule works if you change the reserved topic to some other non-reserved topic. As for permissions, this policy gets created by default:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "iot:Publish",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:162502870742:topic/devices/data"
    }
}
```

I tried modifying the policy to allow MQTT messages to be received:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iot:Publish",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:162502870742:topic/devices/data
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iot:Receive",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

These changes didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: From experience, there are some topics that you cannot subscribe from IoT Rule. I believe the topic you mentioned is one of the reserved topic that AWS uses to send data to that specific device (not going through the mqtt broker but directly sending data on the TCP socket). The same behaviour would occur on IoT jobs, Fleet provisioning topic, your device can subscribe to $aws/things/+/streams/+/data/json but it will not receive messages for other IoT things, only for itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I suspected that this was the case. I wish the AWS documentation would be more clear on which topics can be used with IoT rules. But maybe I'm missing a resource that can be used to help me determine which data is going through the MQTT broker rather than sending it directly on the TCP socket as you pointed out.